# java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependency-injection, dependency-management

I've a dynamic web project named "frontend" who depends on another java project named "dlms". Dlms is a maven project with some dependencies and it works fine.
I've set the dependency of frontend from dlms in that way:

1)Properties of frontend -> deployment assembly -> dlms

2)java buildpath->projects->dlms

3)project references->dlms

if i run the project with this configuration, TomEE server starts but on navigation i've got errors because the maven dependencies are not exported in frontend.

So i've set in project dlms:  properties->java buildpath->order and export and i've check the "maven dependencies" box.

But now TomEE server doesn't start!

Here is the stacktrace:

```
INFORMAZIONI: ------------------------- localhost -> /frontend
nov 09, 2016 1:03:41 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEClassLoaderEnricher validateJarFile
AVVERTENZA: jar'/home/davide/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/frontend/WEB-INF/lib/BINDERfile-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar' contains offending class: javax.validation.Validation. It will be ignored.
nov 09, 2016 1:03:41 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEClassLoaderEnricher validateJarFile
AVVERTENZA: jar '/home/davide/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/frontend/WEB-INF/lib/DUCC-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar' contains offending class: javax.validation.Validation. It will be ignored.
nov 09, 2016 1:03:41 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEClassLoaderEnricher validateJarFile
AVVERTENZA: jar '/home/davide/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/frontend/WEB-INF/lib/SCDP-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar' contains offending class: javax.validation.Validation. It will be ignored.
nov 09, 2016 1:03:41 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEClassLoaderEnricher validateJarFile
AVVERTENZA: jar '/home/davide/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/frontend/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar' contains offending class: javax.persistence.Entity. It will be ignored.
nov 09, 2016 1:03:41 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEClassLoaderEnricher validateJarFile
AVVERTENZA: jar '/home/davide/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/frontend/WEB-INF/lib/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar' contains offending class: javax.annotation.PostConstructbut: You provide javax.annotation API 1.2 so we'll tolerate new classes but it should surely be upgraded in the container
nov 09, 2016 1:03:41 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEClassLoaderEnricher validateJarFile
AVVERTENZA: jar '/home/davide/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/frontend/WEB-INF/lib/javax.inject-1.jar' contains offending class: javax.inject.Inject. It will be ignored.
nov 09, 2016 1:03:41 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEClassLoaderEnricher validateJarFile
AVVERTENZA: jar '/home/davide/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/frontend/WEB-INF/lib/javax.inject-2.4.0-b34.jar' contains offending class: javax.inject.Inject. It will be ignored.
nov 09, 2016 1:03:41 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFORMAZIONI: validateJarFile(/home/davide/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/frontend/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
nov 09, 2016 1:03:41 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEClassLoaderEnricher validateJarFile
AVVERTENZA: jar '/home/davide/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/frontend/WEB-INF/lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar' contains offending class: javax.ws.rs.Pathbut: You provide JAXRS 2 API in the webapp, we tolerate it to support some advanced feature but if you expect TomEE to provide it you should remove it
nov 09, 2016 1:03:41 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEClassLoaderEnricher validateJarFile
AVVERTENZA: jar '/home/davide/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/frontend/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar' contains offending class: javax.transaction.Transaction. It will be ignored.
nov 09, 2016 1:03:41 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEClassLoaderEnricher validateJarFile
AVVERTENZA: jar '/home/davide/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/frontend/WEB-INF/lib/jsr311-api-1.1.2.r612.jar' contains offending class: javax.ws.rs.Path. It will be ignored.
nov 09, 2016 1:03:41 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEClassLoaderEnricher validateJarFile
AVVERTENZA: jar '/home/davide/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/frontend/WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar' contains offending class: javax.validation.Validation. It will be ignored.
nov 09, 2016 1:03:57 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureApplication
INFORMAZIONI: Configuring enterprise application: /home/davide/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/frontend
nov 09, 2016 1:03:59 PM org.apache.openejb.config.InitEjbDeployments deploy
INFORMAZIONI: Auto-deploying ejb eFacade: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=eFacade)
nov 09, 2016 1:03:59 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureService
INFORMAZIONI: Configuring Service(id=Default Managed Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Managed Container)
nov 09, 2016 1:03:59 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig createContainer
INFORMAZIONI: Auto-creating a container for bean frontend.Comp1106966225: Container(type=MANAGED, id=Default Managed Container)
nov 09, 2016 1:03:59 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFORMAZIONI: Creating Container(id=Default Managed Container)
nov 09, 2016 1:03:59 PM org.apache.openejb.core.managed.SimplePassivater init
INFORMAZIONI: Using directory /tmp for stateful session passivation
nov 09, 2016 1:03:59 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder build
INFORMAZIONI: Enterprise application "/home/davide/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/frontend" loaded.
nov 09, 2016 1:03:59 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFORMAZIONI: Assembling app: /home/davide/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/frontend
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/davide/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/frontend/WEB-INF/lib/scattersphere-core-0.0.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/davide/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/frontend/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
nov 09, 2016 1:03:59 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFORMAZIONI: Jndi(name=eFacadeLocalBean) --> Ejb(deployment-id=eFacade)
nov 09, 2016 1:03:59 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFORMAZIONI: Jndi(name=global/frontend/eFacade!bean.facade.Facade) --> Ejb(deployment-id=eFacade)
nov 09, 2016 1:03:59 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFORMAZIONI: Jndi(name=global/frontend/eFacade) --> Ejb(deployment-id=eFacade)
nov 09, 2016 1:03:59 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder initSingleton
INFORMAZIONI: Existing thread singleton service in SystemInstance(): org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@48a242ce
nov 09, 2016 1:03:59 PM org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle startApplication
INFORMAZIONI: OpenWebBeans Container is starting...
nov 09, 2016 1:03:59 PM org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader startUp
INFORMAZIONI: Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [CdiPlugin]
nov 09, 2016 1:03:59 PM org.apache.webbeans.plugins.PluginLoader startUp
INFORMAZIONI: Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [OpenWebBeansJsfPlugin]
nov 09, 2016 1:03:59 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler destroyApplication
INFORMAZIONI: Undeploying app: /home/davide/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/frontend
nov 09, 2016 1:03:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase removeChild
GRAVE: ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/frontend]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:401)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1038)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1537)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1518)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:762)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication(Assembler.java:1982)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:839)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:677)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1261)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1100)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5472)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

nov 09, 2016 1:04:01 PM org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog info
INFORMAZIONI: Using 'openjpa.Log=org.apache.openejb.openjpa.JULOpenJPALogFactory'
nov 09, 2016 1:04:01 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler destroyApplication
INFORMAZIONI: Undeployed app: /home/davide/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/frontend
nov 09, 2016 1:04:01 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder startInternal
GRAVE: Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/frontend]
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: /home/davide/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/frontend: Cannot inherit from final class
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:843)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:677)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1261)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1100)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5472)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3118)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1340)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1827)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.LazyStopWebappClassLoader.loadClass(LazyStopWebappClassLoader.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiScanner.load(CdiScanner.java:299)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiScanner.process(CdiScanner.java:248)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiScanner.init(CdiScanner.java:182)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication(OpenEJBLifecycle.java:180)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.initialize(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:160)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.build(CdiBuilder.java:41)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:777)
    ... 14 more

nov 09, 2016 1:04:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/frontend]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/frontend]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: /home/davide/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/frontend: Cannot inherit from final class
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1270)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1100)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5472)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: /home/davide/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/frontend: Cannot inherit from final class
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:843)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:677)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1261)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3118)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1340)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1827)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.LazyStopWebappClassLoader.loadClass(LazyStopWebappClassLoader.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiScanner.load(CdiScanner.java:299)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiScanner.process(CdiScanner.java:248)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiScanner.init(CdiScanner.java:182)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication(OpenEJBLifecycle.java:180)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.initialize(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:160)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.build(CdiBuilder.java:41)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:777)
    ... 14 more

nov 09, 2016 1:04:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:693)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 6 more

GRAVE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
```

Looking on other similar questions this errors seems to be caused by some conflicts of jar files, but i cannot resolve the problem.

In "frontend" i use only: Apache TomEE web-profile 1.7.4,  tomahawk20 1.1.14

this is the pom.xml of dlms:

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>it.dlms</groupId>
 <artifactId>dlms</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <name>dlms</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <neo4j.version>3.0</neo4j.version>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  <jackson.version>2.7.1</jackson.version>
  <metanome.version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</metanome.version>
 </properties>

 <!-- impostata a 2.5.1 perchè se prende la 3.1 da errore -->
 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.8</source>
     <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
 <dependencies>


  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>3.8.1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <!-- Spark dependency -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>amplab</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-indexedrdd</artifactId>
   <version>0.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- MLIB -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- SPARK-CSV -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-csv_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- Neo4J -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.4</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
     <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.neo4j.test</groupId>
   <artifactId>neo4j-harness</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.4</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.0-M05</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
   <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.4</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapdb/mapdb -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mapdb</groupId>
   <artifactId>mapdb</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.8</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapdb/elsa -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mapdb</groupId>
   <artifactId>elsa</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.bitbucket.kienerj</groupId>
   <artifactId>io</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>net.scattersphere</groupId>
   <artifactId>scattersphere-core</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
   <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
   <version>3.3.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
   <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
   <version>2.6.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
   <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
   <version>6.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- METANOME -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>de.metanome</groupId>
   <artifactId>algorithm_integration</artifactId>
   <version>${metanome.version}</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>de.metanome</groupId>
   <artifactId>algorithm_helper</artifactId>
   <version>${metanome.version}</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>de.metanome</groupId>
   <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
   <version>${metanome.version}</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>metanome.algorithms</groupId>
   <artifactId>BINDERfile</artifactId>
   <version>${metanome.version}</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>metanome.algorithms</groupId>
   <artifactId>DUCC</artifactId>
   <version>${metanome.version}</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>metanome.algorithms</groupId>
   <artifactId>SCDP</artifactId>
   <version>${metanome.version}</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>


  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
   <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
   <version>2.4</version>
   <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
  </dependency>
  <!-- RabbitMQ -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
   <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
   <version>3.6.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-cli/commons-cli -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
   <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
   <version>20.0</version>
  </dependency>


 </dependencies>
 <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>osssonatype</id>
   <name>OSS Sonatype</name>
   <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
   <layout>default</layout>
  </repository>
  <repository>
   <id>snapshots-repo</id>
   <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
   <id>SparkPackagesRepo</id>
   <url>http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven</url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
   <id>Repository at github.com/ankurdave/maven-repo</id>
   <url>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ankurdave/maven-repo/master</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>
</project>
```

(I've also tried to put only dlms jar file into my frontend/Web-inf/lib but got errors related to maven dependencies ).

Comment: Why there are libraries within `frontend/WEB-INF/lib`? If `frontend` is really a Maven project, its dependencies should be taken from the local repository.

Comment: I really don't know, i've tried to delete the folder frontend in 'wtpwebapps' (which is the folder where tomee deploy the application) but it doesn't work. Seems that tomee doesn't deploy automatically the webapp. Maybe i have to change some configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Clean up your dependencies, seems you deliver ee api in the webapp which is forbidden by the spec. Also ensure you use tomee in place through wtp